# Table View Press, how to "let go" of button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I've created a `UITableView`, where I'm able to detect which cell is being pressed. Works great. But it doesn't "let go" of the button, when it has been pressed once. Take a look below.

The button looks like this when the app loads: [image: Button not pressed]
When I tap the button, it looks like this: [image: Button pressed] and it looks like this until another cell is pressed. How do I make the button "let go" of the press, so it looks like a tap, and then looks like the first picture again? The button is in a static table view.

I really searched a long time, and it was hard to find a term for "let go of button".
Thank you!

Comment: Yep, "it stays selected" is the term I'm looking for. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];
}
```

It's a delegate-method that will automatically fire if you've set your ViewController as delegate for the tableView when you select a row.